# move_uploaded _file not functioning correctly

Tags: php

I made a portion for a website that allows csv files to be uploaded and automatically stored in the mysql database. I set up the move_uploaded_file function so that I could make sure that its uploaded correctly, but every time I try uploading something it fails.

The form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="LoadData.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000">
Upload File: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file"><br />
File/Table Name: <input name="filename" type="text"><br />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload File">
</form>
```

The uploading code

```
$FileName = $_POST['filename'];
$target_path = "/director/to/all/uploaded/files/" . $FileName;

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path))
{
    echo "File uploaded correctly </br>";

    //uploads file to database
    mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE....."); //long piece of code that uploads the csv file to the database.table
    echo "Table imported <br/>"';
}
else
{
    echo "The file was no uploaded correctly, the table was not imported.";
}
```

I've checked and the the $_FILES array isn't empty, but the files are not created in the new directory which I've ensured exists and has full permissions. I'm pretty sure my syntax is correct as well; move_uploaded_file(/temporary/file/location/tmp_name.csv, /new/file/location/test.csv) Anyone see where I'm going wrong?

**Update 1**

The results of print_r($_FILES)

( [uploadedfile] => Array ( [name] => Final1.csv [type] => text/comma-separated-values [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpVnOIUK [error] => 0 [size] => 11607 ) )

**Update 2**

No solution has been found, if you think you have an easy answer please post it, but for now I`m going to simply try going around the problem.

Comment: Too abstract without concrete paths (they need to be server-absolute, not webroot-relative) and error messages. And you also shouldn't accept random filenames unfiltered (path traversal).

Comment: If the path exists and `$_FILES` contains the correct data, then the only possibility is a permission problem. The webserver needs sufficient permission to write to the directory where the file should be moved to.

Comment: Nope, no errors besides the 'The file was not uploaded". As for the paths, the destination is set in stone, and the first one is the temporary location of the file when its uploaded, if this can somehow be made made more concrete please tell me how. In regards to the accepting all filenames I'm simply setting up the basics at the moment, but I will keep that in mind and adapt it later on.

Comment: @MrCode, the folder has full permissions, all of them. I made sure of that.

Comment: Can you show the result of `print_r($_FILES)`?

Comment: You're missing a semicolon in line 10. It should be `echo "Table imported <br/>";`

Comment: @AmalMurali, I doublechecked my code and on the server it has the semicolon, I typed it all out instead of transfering the file through scp from the server. And I'll upload the print_r($_FILES) right now.

Comment: The files array looks absolutely fine. I'm still convinced it's a permission problem. When you say it has full permission, define "full permission", is it a Windows or Linux server?

Comment: Its a linux server, the permissions are "drwxrwxrwx". It should have to be globably accessable, just the main user "root" should be fine, but I didn't want to leave it up to chance.

Comment: Show the result of `var_dump(is_writable("/director/to/all/uploaded/files/"))`. Also verify there is actually a value in `$_POST['filename']`.... `var_dump($_POST['filename'])`.

Comment: it returned as false, did not expect that. How would you suggest I fix it? I could create a file in the php code and then overwrite it with move_uploaded_file

Comment: @MrCode, there was also a filename, the one that I had put in the form, as was to be expected. I tried creating a file, but it wouldn't allow me to do it. I tried recreating the directory and giving the permissions as I created it, and still not successful.

Comment: @Mason doesn't look like there's much you can do unless you have root access to the server? I would contact the host because its a server configuration problem.

Comment: @MrCode I have root access to the server that I can use.

Comment: Which user does the webserver run under? What user and what group own the directory? Use ls -l

Comment: I'm pretty sure the server is started by root but different portions of it are handled by seperate sub users. I did a 'whoami' test and its www-data that runs it, and I had made the users of the files and directory root root.

Comment: I think the web server runs under www-data user, and the directory is owned by root:root. This is the problem. Change the directory to be owned by www-data:www-data

Comment: No luck..at this point I think its hopeless unless I wanted to go change the security of the entire server. I`ll just have to try uploading the information from the temporary file and get by without having a copy of the csv file archived.

Comment: Also, whoever wrote the stuff about the upload location in the php.ini it wasn't specified in that file, so it goes to the server default which is the tmp folder which is writable.

Comment: @Mason, that should be working from what you've said, unless the web server runs under something other than root or www-data. `ps aux | grep apache` will show you. If you still want to find a resolution, I suggest posting on serverfault.com (stackoverflow's server admin site).

Answer (score 2):

Your code is blindly assuming success. Never assume that an upload succeeded. Your boilerplate upload-handling code should look more like

```
if ($_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   // it worked, handle the upload
   ...
} else {
   die("Upload failed with error code: " . $_FILES['uploadedfile']['error']);
}
```

The error codes are defined here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: Thanks, I'm still relatively new to php, I'll make sure to add one of the more standard error handling pieces of code.